# How could I execute /_next/static/xxx.js by script tag

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've customize next.config (webpack) to build a static js file (`.next/static/loader.js`).

The original `loader.js` is an IIFE:

```js
(function stickerLoader(){
  alert('Hello');
  // ... some source code
}())
```

And its usage is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_next/static/loader.js"></script>
```

However, the above won't execute immediately, cause it was compile to:

```js
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["static/loader.js"],{

/***/ "./components/Sticker/loader.js":
/*!**************************************!*\
  !*** ./components/Sticker/loader.js ***!
  \**************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

(function stickerLoader() {
  alert('Hello');
  // ... some minified source code
})();

/***/ })

},[["./components/Sticker/loader.js","static/runtime/webpack.js"]]]);
```

Does Next.js has any settings could remove the `WEBPACK WRAPPER`, and leave my source code only, so my expected result would be like:

```js
(function stickerLoader() {
  alert('Hello');
  // ... some minified source code
})();
```

My `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    return merge(config, {
      entry() {
        return config.entry().then(entry => {
          return Object.assign({}, entry, {
            'static/loader.js': path.resolve(
              __dirname,
              'components',
              'Sticker',
              'loader.js'
            )
          });
        });
      }
    });
 };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it without any webpack stuff, why do you add it to the webpack build?

If this is a simple js file, put it in the `public/` (or `static/` at v9.0.5 and below) folder as a regular static js file.

Comment: I agree your opinion which is also my current solution: I wrote a standalone script to call `terser` to minify multiple `loader.js` and write the result to `public/`.

Comment: I'm just curious to know if `next.js` have some alternative ways to achieve my objective...